# Finding the browser with php

Tags: php, css, browser, find

Which is the right way to detect the browser with which the user views the page with php?

I tried with get_browser, it gave something like:

```
Array (
  [browser_name_regex] => §^.*$§
  [browser_name_pattern] => * 
  [browser] => Default Browser 
  [version] => 0 
  [majorver] => 0 
  [minorver] => 0 
  [platform] => unknown 
  [alpha] => 
  [beta] => 
  [win16] => 
  [win32] => 
  [win64] => 
  [frames] => 1 
  [iframes] => 
  [tables] => 1 
  [cookies] => 
  [backgroundsounds] => 
  [cdf] => 
  [vbscript] => 
  [javaapplets] => 
  [javascript] => 
  [activexcontrols] => 
  [isbanned] => 
  [ismobiledevice] => 
  [issyndicationreader] => 
  [crawler] => 
  [cssversion] => 0 
  [supportscss] => 
  [aol] => 
  [aolversion] => 0
)
```

this is what i got for IE7,chrome and mozilla firefox.

I tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and it gave me  `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.0; en-US) AppleWebKit/534.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0.552.237 Safari/534.10`

I am able to get some info here.

So please tell me if there was a better way to do this, and is this a good solution to display HTML contents with different CSS for different browsers?

Comment: are you saying get get firefox for all browsers? If so I think there is a problem in your code somewhere else.  please post more code. But I can promise the function works :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the best way to detect a browser with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819226/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-browser-with-php)

Comment: This question has been asked many times before. See my duplicate note above for an example. The short answer is that you cannot reliably detect the browser from the server.

Comment: when using get_browser function array reference of 'browser' gives as 'default browser' for all three browsers . i dont get it why?

Comment: Actually, the IE user agent says Mozilla as well, it looks like this but changes depending on version (in this case IE 7 on WinXP): `Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)`

Comment: @rajprashanth r - I have written an answer that tries to explain the why you're not getting any useful data out of `get_browser`, how to fix it if you want to, but why `get_browser` in general is probably a bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Quoting [this](http://apptools.com/phptools/browser/) blog :

> Browser detection is an illusive task that is ultimately doomed to fail. Browsers are always changing and keeping up to date with these changes is a continuous job. Some browsers allow the user to alter the way the browser identifies itself, or to not identify itself at all. Some firewalls block the sending of the browser identification, so no browser detection scheme is entirely successful.

**NOTE :** also, read more about browser detection bad practice [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/browser_detection_and_cross_browser_support).

However, that being said here's [a script](http://www.phpclasses.org/browse/file/12369.html) I once used :

```
<?php

/**
 * Class to detect which browser is currently accessing the page/site
 * @author Paul Scott
 * This class is very loosely based on scripts by Gary White
 * @copyright Paul Scott
 * @package browser
 */

class browser 
{
    /**
     * @var string $name
     */
    var $name = NULL;

    /**
     * @var string $version
     */
    var $version = NULL;

    /**
     * @var $useragent
     */
    var $useragent = NULL;

    /**
     * @var string $platform
     */
    var $platform;

    /**
     * @var string aol
     */
    var $aol = FALSE;

    /**
     * @var string browser
     */
    var $browsertype;

    /**
     * Class constructor
     * @param void
     * @return void
     */
    function browser()
    {
        $agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
        //set the useragent property
        $this->useragent = $agent;
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the browser details from the USER_AGENT string in 
     * the PHP superglobals
     * @param void
     * @return string property platform 
     */
    function getBrowserOS()
    {
        $win = eregi("win", $this->useragent);
        $linux = eregi("linux", $this->useragent);
        $mac = eregi("mac", $this->useragent);
        $os2 = eregi("OS/2", $this->useragent);
        $beos = eregi("BeOS", $this->useragent);

        //now do the check as to which matches and return it
        if($win)
        {
            $this->platform = "Windows";
        }
        elseif ($linux)
        {
            $this->platform = "Linux"; 
        }
        elseif ($mac)
        {
            $this->platform = "Macintosh"; 
        }
        elseif ($os2)
        {
            $this->platform = "OS/2"; 
        }
        elseif ($beos)
        {
            $this->platform = "BeOS"; 
        }
        return $this->platform;
    }

    /**
     * Method to test for Opera
     * @param void
     * @return property $broswer
     * @return property version
     * @return bool false on failure
     */
    function isOpera()
    {
        // test for Opera       
        if (eregi("opera",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = stristr($this->useragent, "opera");
            if (eregi("/", $val)){
                $val = explode("/",$val);
                $this->browsertype = $val[0];
                $val = explode(" ",$val[1]);
                $this->version = $val[0];
            }else{
                $val = explode(" ",stristr($val,"opera"));
                $this->browsertype = $val[0];
                $this->version = $val[1];
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for FireFox
     * @param void
     * @return bool false on failure
     */ 
    function isFirefox()
    {
        if(eregi("Firefox", $this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "Firefox"; 
            $val = stristr($this->useragent, "Firefox");
            $val = explode("/",$val);
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return true;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for Konquerer
     * @param void
     * @return prop $browser
     * @return prop $version
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isKonqueror()
    {
        if(eregi("Konqueror",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"Konqueror"));
            $val = explode("/",$val[0]);
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = str_replace(")","",$val[1]);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }

    }//end func

    /**
     * Method to check for Internet Explorer v1
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     * @return prop $browsertype
     * @return prop $version
     */
    function isIEv1()
    {
        if(eregi("microsoft internet explorer", $this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "MSIE"; 
            $this->version = "1.0";
            $var = stristr($this->useragent, "/");
            if (ereg("308|425|426|474|0b1", $var))
            {
                $this->version = "1.5";
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//end function

    /**
     * Method to check for Internet Explorer later than v1
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     * @return prop $browsertype
     * @return prop $version
     */
    function isMSIE()
    {
        if(eregi("msie", $this->useragent) && !eregi("opera",$this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "MSIE"; 
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"msie"));
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];

            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//end function

    /**
     * Method to check for Galeon
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isGaleon()
    {
        if(eregi("galeon",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"galeon"));
            $val = explode("/",$val[0]);
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//end func

    /**
     * Now we do the tests for browsers I can't test...
     * If someone finds a bug, please report it ASAP to me please!
     */

    /**
     * Method to check for WebTV browser
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     * @return prop $browsertype
     * @return prop $version
     */
    function isWebTV()
    {
        if(eregi("webtv",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode("/",stristr($this->useragent,"webtv"));
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for BeOS's NetPositive
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     * @return prop $browsertype
     * @return prop $version
     */
    function isNetPositive()
    {
        if(eregi("NetPositive", $this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode("/",stristr($this->useragent,"NetPositive"));
            $this->platform = "BeOS"; 
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for MSPIE (Pocket IE)
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isMSPIE()
    {
        if(eregi("mspie",$this->useragent) || eregi("pocket", $this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"mspie"));
            $this->browsertype = "MSPIE"; 
            $this->platform = "WindowsCE"; 
            if (eregi("mspie", $this->useragent))
                $this->version = $val[1];
            else {
                $val = explode("/",$this->useragent);
                $this->version = $val[1];
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to test for iCab
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isIcab()
    {
        if(eregi("icab",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"icab"));
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to test for the OmniWeb Browser
     * @param void
     * @return bool True on success
     */
    function isOmniWeb()
    {
        if(eregi("omniweb",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode("/",stristr($this->useragent,"omniweb"));
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for Phoenix Browser
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isPhoenix()
    {
        if(eregi("Phoenix", $this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "Phoenix"; 
            $val = explode("/", stristr($this->useragent,"Phoenix/"));
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for Firebird
     * @param void
         * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isFirebird()
    {
        if(eregi("firebird", $this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "Firebird"; 
            $val = stristr($this->useragent, "Firebird");
            $val = explode("/",$val);
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for Mozilla alpha/beta
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isMozAlphaBeta()
    {
        if(eregi("mozilla",$this->useragent) && 
           eregi("rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]",$this->useragent) && 
           !eregi("netscape",$this->useragent))

        {
            $this->browsertype = "Mozilla"; 
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"rv:"));
            eregi("rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]",$this->useragent,$val);
            $this->version = str_replace("rv:","",$val[0]);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//end function

    /**
     * Method to check for Mozilla Stable versions
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isMozStable()
    {
        if(eregi("mozilla",$this->useragent) &&
           eregi("rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]",$this->useragent) && 
           !eregi("netscape",$this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "Mozilla"; 
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"rv:"));
            eregi("rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]",$this->useragent,$val);
            $this->version = str_replace("rv:","",$val[0]);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to check for Lynx and Amaya
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isLynx()
    {
        if(eregi("libwww", $this->useragent))
        {
            if (eregi("amaya", $this->useragent))
            {
                $val = explode("/",stristr($this->useragent,"amaya"));
                $this->browsertype = "Amaya"; 
                $val = explode(" ", $val[1]);
                $this->version = $val[0];
            } else {
                $val = explode("/",$this->useragent);
                $this->browsertype = "Lynx"; 
                $this->version = $val[1];
            }
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * method to check for safari browser
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isSafari()
        {
        if(eregi("safari", $this->useragent))
        {
            $this->browsertype = "Safari"; 
            $this->version = "";
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Various tests for Netscrape
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on success
     */
    function isNetscape()
    {
        if(eregi("netscape",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"netscape"));
            $val = explode("/",$val[0]);
            $this->browsertype = $val[0];
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        elseif(eregi("mozilla",$this->useragent) && 
                !eregi("rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]\.[0-9]",$this->useragent))
        {
            $val = explode(" ",stristr($this->useragent,"mozilla"));
            $val = explode("/",$val[0]);
            $this->browsertype = "Netscape"; 
            $this->version = $val[1];
            return TRUE;
        }
        else {
            return FALSE;
        }
    }//end func

    /**
     * Method to check for AOL connections
     * @param void
     * @return bool true on Success
     */
    function isAOL()
    {
        if (eregi("AOL", $this->useragent)){
            $var = stristr($this->useragent, "AOL");
            $var = explode(" ", $var);
            $this->aol = ereg_replace("[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z]", "", $var[1]);
            return TRUE;
        }
        else { 
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Method to tie them all up and output something useful
     * @param void
     * @return array
     */
    function whatBrowser()
    {
        $this->getBrowserOS();
        $this->isOpera();
        $this->isFirefox();
        $this->isKonqueror();
        $this->isIEv1();
        $this->isMSIE();
        $this->isGaleon();
        $this->isNetPositive();
        $this->isMSPIE();
        $this->isIcab();
        $this->isOmniWeb();
        $this->isPhoenix();
        $this->isFirebird();
        $this->isLynx();
        $this->isSafari();
        //$this->isMozAlphaBeta();
        //$this->isMozStable();
        //$this->isNetscape();
        $this->isAOL();
        return array('browsertype' => $this->browsertype, 
                     'version' => $this->version, 
                     'platform' => $this->platform, 
                     'AOL' => $this->aol); 
    }
}//end class
?>
```

As per mentioned, [conditional comments](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) may only work with IE, however you'll solve about 90% of the problems right there.

On another note, you may find [Zend_Locale](http://framework.zend.com/code/filedetails.php?repname=Zend+Framework&path=/trunk/library/Zend/Locale.php) interesting to return browser language, etc.

In any case, you'll be better off targeting which browser you wish to support the most, focus on that one and try to be compliant with other browsers in the end. (It's always a good idea to "Target the standards and not particular browsers", though.) It's a damn task that we all have to go through (unless one use frameworks such as Echo2, GWT, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

unless you have a very complex design you should try to use the same css for every browser and cross-browser optimize it, which works best if you have a simple and clear html-structure.

this will keep you sane, since you don't have to maintain a lot of different css-files, which becomes more work as the site ages.

**IE6** might be a very special case, there you could use the conditional statements centr0 mentioned

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're not getting useful data out of `get_browser` is because `get_browser` isn't magic.

It requires you to have a file on your server named `browsecap.ini`, which defines how it should work out what the browser is and what its capable of.

There is a note about browsecap.ini on the PHP manual page for `get_browser` -- https://www.php.net/get_browser. This note also explains that browsecap.ini is not supplied as standard with PHP, but provides a link to where you can get an up-to-date version of it.

The `browsecap.ini` file needs to be kept up-to-date by the owner of the site (ie you) whenever a new version of any browser is released, otherwise you will quickly start getting bad results.

However, even with an up-to-date `browsecap.ini` file, you *still* can't rely on `get_browser` to give you an accurate answer, because the data that it looks at to determine the browser can be spoofed by the browser -- for example, Firefox has an option to make it pretend to be various versions of IE, and most other browsers have similar features. This will completely fool `get_browser`. There is no way around this.

A far better approach would be to use Javascript on the client-side to determine which features the browser supports. See my [answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819226/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-browser-with-php) for further advice on this.

I hope that answers your question.

Comment: +1 from me, also for your linked answer, even if i'm kind of an minimalist concerning javascript-enhancing basic browser-functionality, perhaps because of my enterprise- and public sector institutions-client background with a lot of IE6 and high-accessibility sites in the mix and harsh security concerns.

Answer (score 0):

Conditional statements work without the use of PHP.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Answer (score 0):

i found a nice blog on this title
http://quicklesson.info/article/how-to-find-browser-name-using-php

Comment: It's better to post the answer itself here, rather than relying on links. Links get broken, and it will help other users of this site if the answer is here.