# How to filter access by User Browser type and version

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, ajax

**My question based on :**

My web application building by PHP, AJAX, Javascript, CSS, and others
 not really support with old / really old browser. Some function/style
 maybe can't running on old version browser.

**So My main question is :**

How to detect and set restrict/allowed based on Browser Type (IE,
 Mozilla, Chrome, etc) and the browser version with PHP/JavaScript/AJAX?

Comment: what kind of restriction ?

Comment: Keep in mind that any solution you come up with can be bypassed since it will be based on what the user is reporting.

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php

Comment: This is all available in PHP docs.

Comment: Please never mark an answer as correct if they cut and past something from a manual.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the best way to detect a browser with php?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4819226/whats-the-best-way-to-detect-a-browser-with-php)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1895727/how-can-i-detect-the-browser-with-php-or-javascript

Comment: Always do LOTS of research before asking a question.  This helps to reduce bloat on SO.  99.9% of the time, anything you ever dream to ask has already been answered on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Javascript this is how you could do it like this to get the browser the user is using and also the browser version they are currently using.

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
        function browserDetails() {
            var user_agent = navigator.userAgent,
                tem, M = user_agent.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
            if (/trident/i.test(M[1])) {
                tem = /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(user_agent) || [];
                return {
                    name: 'IE ',
                    version: (tem[1] || '')
                };
            }
            if (M[1] === 'Chrome') {
                tem = user_agent.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
                if (tem != null) {
                    return {
                        name: 'Opera',
                        version: tem[1]
                    };
                }
            }
            M = M[2] ? [M[1], M[2]] : [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
            if ((tem = user_agent.match(/version\/(\d+)/i)) != null) {
                M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
            }
            return {
                name: M[0],
                version: M[1]
            };
        }
    
            //display browser
        var browser = browserDetails();
        console.log(browser.name);
        console.log(browser.version);
    </script>
```

> **NB**: the above code does not detect Microsoft Edge, you will need to research on how to detect if user is using edge, then implement
>   with the code above.

Then if you want to get a specif browser name and version this is how you will do it.

```
var browser=browserDetails();
    if(browser.name == 'Chrome' && browser.version <= 28)
        {
            // then do your restrictions
        }else{

            // do something
        }
```

**PS :
This does work also for IE bellow screenshot**

[image]

Comment: name: 'IE ' too much white space ?

Comment: you can reduce the white space, but it does work I did test it

Comment: @Michael see my updated answer with screenshot from IE, what IE u using?

Comment: MSIE 8 i think.

Comment: still does't detected?

Comment: I think every method have their advantages and disadvantages. I accept the solution above for one of the solution so i will mark this as the answer. Thank you

Comment: pleasure, glad I could help

Answer (score 3):

### PHP mannual [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

**Listing all information about the users browser**

```
<?php
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

**Example :-**

```
<?php
function getBrowser()
{
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
}

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```